# How to disable open, save prompt while opening a video in BlackBerry default player?

Tags: blackberry, video

In my application, I'm opening videos in the default BlackBerry player. But each time I select a video it's showing a prompt "open/save/cancel" . How can we disable this prompt and go straight to the player?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When opening a file from within your own application, you can use the content handler API to invoke the BlackBerry player without opening an open/save/cancel dialog. There is an example of how to use the content handler API [here](http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/Invoke-the-Media-application/ta-p/442964). That should do exactly what you need.